# SBT including the version number in a program

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.9

I want a program I'm building to be able to report its own version at runtime (e.g. `scala myprog.jar --version`). Traditionally in a maven project, I'd use resource filtering (pom.xml -> file.properties -> read value at runtime). I know there's [sbt-filter-plugin](https://bitbucket.org/wyuenho/sbt-filter-plugin/wiki/Home) to emulate this functionality, but I'm curious if there's a more standard / preferred / clever way of doing this in SBT.

tl;dr how can I read the version number defined in `build.sbt` at runtime?

Comment: The right idiomatic way to do this nowadays is via sbt-buildinfo https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo/.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Update...

https://github.com/ritschwumm/xsbt-reflect (mentioned above) is Obsolete, but there is this cool SBT release tool that can automatically manage versions and more: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release.

Alternatively, if you want a quick fix you can get version from manifest like this:

```
val version: String = getClass.getPackage.getImplementationVersion
```

This value will be equal to `version` setting in your project which you set either in `build.sbt` or `Build.scala`.

Another Update ...

Buildinfo SBT plugin can generate a class with version number based on `build.sbt`:

```
/** This object was generated by sbt-buildinfo. */
case object BuildInfo {
  /** The value is "helloworld". */
  val name: String = "helloworld"
  /** The value is "0.1-SNAPSHOT". */
  val version: String = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  /** The value is "2.10.3". */
  val scalaVersion: String = "2.10.3"
  /** The value is "0.13.2". */
  val sbtVersion: String = "0.13.2"
  override val toString: String = "name: %s, version: %s, scalaVersion: %s, sbtVersion: %s" format (name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion)
}
```

See the docs on how to enable it here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo/.

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives a `null` for me. sbt 0.13.8, JDK 8, Scala 2.11.7

Comment: Yes, it shows in the output jar filename and so forth. But the project is not making any Maven pom, it's a standalone executable. I assume this is the reason it wouldn't get these implementation / specification versions etc. Any pointers are welcome - I'm not from a Java background so these feel a bit overengineered to me. :)

Comment: @akauppi I'm puzzled by your comments ;). Is your build based on SBT, could you paste the filename and the bit of code that sets the version? What do you mean by "standalone executable" and "making pom"? Thanks

Comment: I could discuss this on email. Do you mean '.getImplementationVersion' should work on a bare sbt project, without any other packaging?

Comment: I don't know what @akauppi's problem ended up being, but for me `null` was printed because I ran my app with `sbt run`, which obviously doesn't use the metadata from the .jar file. If run using `java -cp somepath my.main.Class` or any other way that runs the actual compiled .jar, the version is printed as expected.

Comment: @dskrvk You probably guessed my problem just right!

Comment: Can you please add a comment mentioning that the idiomatic way of doing this in sbt/sbt is via https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo/? @yǝsʞǝlA

Answer (score 8):

Use the [xsbt-reflect](https://github.com/ritschwumm/xsbt-reflect) plugin. It will generate a source file that contains, among other things, the project version number.

Answer (score 5):

In general, without any plugins, you can do something like this:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  val file = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "foo" / "bar" / "BuildInfo.scala"

  IO.write(
    file,
    s"""package foo.bar
       |object BuildInfo {
       |  val Version = "${version.value}"
       |}""".stripMargin
  )

  Seq(file)
}.taskValue
```

And then do with `foo.bar.BuildInfo.Version` constant whatever you like.

Or more general:

```
def generateBuildInfo(packageName: String,
                      objectName: String = "BuildInfo"): Setting[_] =
  sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
    val file =
      packageName
        .split('.')
        .foldLeft((sourceManaged in Compile).value)(_ / _) / s"$objectName.scala"

    IO.write(
      file,
      s"""package $packageName
         |object $objectName {
         |  val Version = "${version.value}"
         |}""".stripMargin
    )

    Seq(file)
  }.taskValue
```

Example:

```
settings(generateBuildInfo("foo.bar"))
```

You can even change this to pass object properties as a `Map[String, String]` and generate the object appropriately.

Comment: this is helpful. Im using `(scalaSource in Compile).value` but i might think about that

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making the build system (I use a `Makefile` on top of `sbt`) prepare a `src/main/resources/version.txt` file for Scala to read.

In the `Makefile`:

```
$(RESOURCES_VERSION): build.sbt
    grep "^version := " $< | cut -f2 -d\" > $@
```

In Scala:

```
val version: String = {
  val src = Source.fromURL( getClass.getResource("/version.txt") )
  src.getLines.next   // just take the first line 
}
```

This works for me.

It's curious that such a needed feature (I would think) is not easily available in Scala. A very simple `sbt` plugin just for this would be welcome.

Comment: It's easily available in vanilla sbt, see my answer.