# scala reference sbt project version

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a scala play application; I am trying to expose health check for our service. Part of the health check I would like to capture the project artifact version.

Can I know how I can reference project artifact version from health check controller in play application. We are making use of **sbt** for the build.

**sample sbt file**

import *root*.sbt.Keys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import NativePackagerKeys._
import play.PlayScala

name := "artifact-name"

***version := "0.5"***

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7")

scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.7"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

Comment: seem's similar question is already posted; I got the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957025/sbt-including-the-version-number-in-a-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [xsbt-reflect plugin](https://github.com/ritschwumm/xsbt-reflect) gives you access to the SBT variables at runtime.

All you need to do inside of your health route is return

```
Reflect.version
```