# How to include the application's version number in a Scala.js program?

Tags: sbt, scala.js

Basically, I'm curious if something like [SBT including the version number in a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957025/sbt-including-the-version-number-in-a-program) is possible for Scala.js. The proposed solution doesn't work in scala.js, apparently due the the absence of the `getPackage` method:

```
[error] Referring to non-existent method java.lang.Class.getPackage()java.lang.Package
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) for that. The Usage section of the readme contains everything you need.